# Display images in gridview on runtime programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using a form to insert data. This form has a file upload control that I am using to upload an image. I have used DataAdapter and Dataset to display the data that will be displayed after searching using the keywords. Therefore, I assigned the dataset to the gridview. Now, the problem is that I want to display the images while the dataset that is assigned to the gridview, can't have images. How can I display images along with the data in dataset?
Here is my code:

```
public string getConString()
{
    return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(getConString());
    string inp = Request.QueryString["srch"].ToString();
    string qry = "select Category,Title,Make,Model,Condition,Price from product WHERE Category like '%" + inp + "%' OR title like '%" + inp + "%' OR make like '%" + inp + "%'OR city like '%" + inp + "%'OR state like '%" + inp + "%'";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    con.Open();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a template field with your gridview. This allows you to edit how each column is displayed. This goes in place of your bound field.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName"> 
<ItemTemplate>
     <%# Bind("FirstName") %> <img src="..." />
     or <img src='<%# Bind("ImageLocation_db_column") %>' />
</ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. But I couldn't do it successfully. Could you explain it in more detail please. I also want to show details of a single row onto the second page.

Answer (score 0):

Set the GridView's AutoGenerateColumns property to false, then put in your grid's source code the columns manually.

The images can be showed on this way:

```
<Columns>
<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="image field of your dataset"></asp:ImageField>
</Columns>
```